# Why is my entire home backed up?

Tags: bash, backup, cp, read

I wish to back up some of the files located in my home dir.
That is

- simple files at the root of my home
- and some directories in my home, listed in ~/worthsaving.txt

Sample worthsaving.txt:

```
cloud
work/web
work/python
```

I made this script :

```bash
#!/bin/bash
srce=/home/poor
dest=/run/media/poor/backup
mkdir -p $dest

cp -v $srce/* $dest/ # simple files

while IFS= read -r worth
do
    mkdir -p $dest/$worth
    cp -Rv $srce/$worth $dest/$worth # dirs that matters
done < "$srce/worthsaving.txt"
```

But I end up with not only what I wish but my entire home in a dir called `poor` at the root of the backup.

What's wrong ?

Comment: Is there an empty line in `worthsaving.txt`?

Comment: Double quote all your variables where you use them, and try again

Comment: Since Kamil has already explained the issue, I'll add this as a comment...wrap the 'cp..' in `if [ ! -z "${worth}" ]; then ... fi`

Comment: Your question already has a good answer, so I'll just recommend using `rsync -av` instead of `cp -Rv`.  rsync only copies new and modified files, so will be much faster on subsequent runs.  See `man rsync` for details of `-a`, `-v`, and **many** other options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a blank line in your list of files to backup. Inside the loop this means that `$worth` is empty, which in turn results in execution of this command:

```
cp -Rv /home/poor /run/media/poor/backup/
```

In case it's not yet clear, this copies your entire home directory to the target directory `poor` in the destination.

Here's what your loop could correctly look like:

```
while IFS= read -r worth
do
    if [ -n "$worth" ] && [ -d "$worth" ]
    then
        mkdir -p "$dest/$worth"
        cp -Rv "$srce/$worth" "$dest/$worth" # dirs that matters
    fi
done < "$srce/worthsaving.txt"
```

Although as has been hinted in the comments you could replace all of this with `rsync`:

```
rsync -rtR --files-from "$srce/worthsaving.txt" "$srce/" "$dest/"
```

Personally I'd use `-a` (`--archive`) instead of `-rt` (`--recursive --times`) but as you didn't use `cp -a` I've stuck with the minimal recommended flags for `rsync` too.

As an aside, *always* double-quote your variables<sup>*</sup> when you use them. This protects them from word splitting and globbing by the shell. As an example consider a directory `my bin` assigned by the loop to `$worth`. Without double-quotes, this would result in this erroneous and unexpected command:

```
cp -Rv /home/poor/my bin /run/media/poor/backup/my bin
```

Here, an attempt would be made to copy three files or directories (`/home/poor/my`, `bin` from the current directory, and `/run/media/poor/backup/my`) to the target directory `bin`

---

<sup>* At least, always until you understand why you might have a specific case not to do so. And even then, reconsider.</sup>